# MacBook Air - upgraded HD, now does not boot up

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, startup, upgrade

Upgraded my hard drive from a 250gb to a 500gb. After reinstalling Mountain Lion, I did a restore from my TM backup. All seemed to go well, and was quick.

The system told me to reboot after the install and again all was good, but it won’t complete the boot. Apple symbol comes up, progress bar starts up, slows down, then stops. I am looking at a screen that is ready to start the GUI, but... it just sits. I tried restarting, no different.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can try starting in Safe Mode. Restart your Mac and immediately after your Mac starts (some Mac computers play a startup sound), press and hold the Shift key. Release the Shift key when you see the progress indicator. See if this works. If so edit your question mentioning that it works in safe mode, and leave a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the company I got the HD from. I was sent a document that corrected me issue thankfully. I was starting my MacBook with the CMD-R and not the CMD-OPT-R opt. The 2nd option actually loaded Catalina. From there isn’t was a matter of reloading my data from my TM backup.

It has been working all day, and seems to be fine. I have run all of my programs and all is good.

Thanks to all that replied.